# $data['main_content'] to load view in subfolder in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter

Here is my function:

```
function single_resonator() {
            $data['title'] = 'Single Resonator Operating Parameters';
            $data['main_content'] = 'products/single_res_view';
            $this->load->view('templates/main.php', $data);
        }
```

But the single_res_view doesn't load if it is in the products folder in the views folder.  How do I accomplish this?  I tried a file called MY_router.php from a post elsewhere on this site and it didn't help.  CI will only load the single_res_view if it is in the root of the views folder.

Here is templates/main.php

```
<?php $this->load->view('includes/header.php'); ?>

<?php $this->load->view('includes/nav.php'); ?>

<?php $this->load->view($main_content); ?>

<?php $this->load->view('includes/footer.php'); ?>
```

Comment: we need your 'templates/main.php' code...

Comment: so the sub folder "includes" is working in your views directory?

Comment: your 'single_res_view' is a php file correct? maybe try 'products/single_res_view.php' ... event though you shouldn't have to do that.  and you're sure it's products/ and not product/ ?

Comment: Yes, it is php.  I'll try that.

Comment: Nope that didn't help to add .php

Comment: make sure your directory is products and not product, because if this is all correct it should work.

Comment: Directory is called products.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this:

```
$data['main_content'] = 'products/single_res_view.php';
```

If not, can you triple check that the path and file names are correct? Otherwise, can you echo the value of $main_content just in case you're overwriting it somewhere?

Comment: That's what I have, isn't it?

Comment: Can you detail your exact directory structure in your views folder?

Comment: It echoes as single_res_view without the products directory.

Comment: Sorry, I moved files around. Thanks for helping me track that down.

Comment: @shummel7845: no worries..happens to the best of us :-]